# Twitter Post Status Characters Scrambled If Image Included

Tags: twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

Posting the following message to twitter (this was a test for foreign characters):

> ?===)")+"45(&/*ç)    sdlkfnaslfn k -..,$äöü¨;:_:;>>><<<>>°+°+"*ç
>   http://www.bbc.co.uk

**via the API** (v1.1), without an included image URL, produces:

[image]

Which is the expected output. Posting the same message, this time with an image URL, produces:

[image]

Note the `?` symbols where the message has been garbled. I am at a total loss to explain this behaviour as the posted status characters to the API are, per byte, identical.

I am interacting with the Twitter API via Java Spring Social (v1.1.0)